# Convert altitude to stairs

Tags: lua, altitude, watchmaker

I have a Huawei Watch 2 which has altitude support using the {aalt} tag in WatchMaker and an Android phone.

How can I use this tag to convert to staircases climbed?

In the Huawei Health app it shows a "Climbed" reading which it converts to an approximation of staircases climbed but I don't know how to do this.

If I just record changes in altitude it could be going up or down.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. TIA